# Looping variables using index C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I looked for something relating to this, but could not find anything.

Is there a way to use an index that attaches to a variable?

What I have so far is:

```
string tagName1 = tagNameBoxAMT1.Text;
string tagName2 = tagNameBoxAMT2.Text;
string tagName3 = tagNameBoxAMT3.Text;
string tagName4 = tagNameBoxAMT4.Text;
string tagName5 = tagNameBoxAMT5.Text;
string tagName6 = tagNameBoxAMT6.Text;
```

and what I would like to have is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
     string tagNamei = tagNameBoxAMTi.Text;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You should add the variables to a list (array, list, set) and then access each position of the list inside your `loop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manage a list of such controls:

```
var tagNames = new List<YourControl>() {
    tagNameBoxAMT1, tagNameBoxAMT2, tagNameBoxAMT3, tagNameBoxAMT4, tagNameBoxAMT5, tagNameBoxAMT6
};
```

and then you can use it appropriately:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    string tagNamei = tagNames[i].Text;
}
```

If `tagNameBoxAMT1` and others are fields/properties, you *could* use Reflection to do it automatically but it is rather not recommended.

If you would like to go with Reflection approach, here is the sample code:

```
class SomeWindow
{
    private SomeControl tagNameBoxAMT1;
    private SomeControl tagNameBoxAMT2;
    private SomeControl tagNameBoxAMT3;

    public SomeWindow()
    {
        tagNameBoxAMT1 = new SomeControl() { Text = "Text1" };
        tagNameBoxAMT2 = new SomeControl() { Text = "Text2" };
        tagNameBoxAMT3 = new SomeControl() { Text = "Text3" };
    }

    public void GiveMeWithReflection()
    {
        var thisType = typeof(SomeWindow);
        var controlType = typeof(SomeControl);

        var textProperty = controlType.GetProperty("Text");

        var props = thisType.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                                       System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                            .Where(fi => fi.Name.StartsWith("tagNameBoxAMT"));
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var control = prop.GetValue(this);
            var tagName = textProperty.GetValue(control);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Thought there would be a different way such as using CodeDom or something similar. This is definitely good enough.

Comment: @NateM24 I've just updated with the possible Reflection approach.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will document this for future use! For now, your first solution works perfectly.

Comment: I have not, but I definitely will. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure,to do this the `TextBoxes` to be on the Form directly, **not inside a container** :)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

 string[] array = this.Controls.OfType < TextBox > ().Select(r => r.Text).ToArray();

 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(array[i]); //This is used to dispaly array values
 }

}
```

you can also try this, use a simple `foreach` loop like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
       {
           if (c is TextBox)
           list.Add((c as TextBox).Text);

       }
```